# Allowing use of a UDF in one open workbook but make it invisible/unusable/inaccessible in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, user-defined-functions

I have two fairly simple UDFs in a workbook (`Book 1`) that I have also registered with the function wizard. Everything works seamlessly. However, when I have two different workbooks open - `Book 1` and `Book 2` - I'm able to use either one of the two UDFs from `Book 1` in `Book 2`. `Book 2` doesn't have them registered under the function wizard in the same manner as `Book 1`, but the functions are still fully functional.

Here is a picture of how each workbook currently appears:

**Book 1**                     **Book 2**
[image: both workbook function wizards]

**<s>Short of creating an add-in,</s> Is there a way to code this so that the UDFs in** `Book 1` **are *only visible in*** `Book 1`**, despite any other workbooks that may be open?**

**EDIT:**

So an add-in may not even be possible. However, is there another way to attack this so that the only workbook that can use the functions is `Book 1`?

---

<sup>Note: `Option Private Module` doesn't work as it then hides the functions from the user in both books, but it does stop `Book 2` from being able to use the function. **My end goal** is to have it visible in `Book 1` but invisible and unusable in `Book 2`.</sup>

Comment: (moved from now-deleted not-quite-an-answer) I don't think it's possible: the UDF is `Public` and has to be - the `Friend` modifier would do exactly what you need, but it's illegal in a standard module, and as far as I can tell (I might be wrong here - tried & failed, maybe others can figure that one out) you can't register a UDF that's in a worksheet or workbook module (where `Friend` accessibility would be legal, since document modules are class modules). I don't think an add-in would prevent `Book2` from seeing the UDFs either, since add-ins are loaded at application level, at startup.

Comment: UDF in a `Option Private Module` Module? Haven't tested so not sure if this is an answer yet.

Comment: @AJD, that won't work, unfortunately. I have a note at the bottom of my post explaining what happens. I hoped that would work too, which is why I tried it initially. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain you can make it so that the function doesn't appear at all while in a different workbook. They are all under the same `Application` and so they are sort of related.

You can use `Application.Caller` which will contain the Range object that triggered the UDF:

```
 If Application.Caller.Parent.Parent.Name <> "Book1.xlsm" Then Exit Function
```

And essentially return nothing causing the function to be worthless, and if you put this high up in your code (as the first line of the function) it will use very limited resources.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible not only because Function Wizard works in application level but also VBA compiling is caller-independed. For example let set a compiler conditional statement

```
#If ActiveWorkbook = ThisWorkbook Then

 Public Function udf1()
  udf1 = "UDF1"
 End Function

#End If
```

this evaluates to `True` in compiler time and one can see `udf1` in both workbooks. When calling this function from book2, this statement evaluates to `False`. However the function is still accessible from both books because the compilation was done in a previous - caller independed - time, when each module was compiling and this statement was true each time.

Of course  `#If ActiveWorkbook <>ThisWorkbook` ... makes it unviewable for both.